# koji build : 'no package found for libcman.so.3'

Tags: koji

I'm using a koji to build a package. In error, it's saying:

> Error: Package: pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.10-14.el6.x86_64 (build)
>              Requires: libcman.so.3()(64bit)

What does it exactly mean?

'libcman.so' is in the package 'cluster'. Then I built the clusterlib, and add it into my build, but didn't fix the problem after I put 'cluster' into 'BuildRequires' since another problem 'no package found for cluster' came out.

I think I'm not on the correct track.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix it, but did some work around to avoid it. It's '.so', so I don't think the python module I build really need it here. So I commented it out from the spec file. and Just ensure I have these packages installed at the server before I install the new python module.